# Aligning text vertically in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to know the correct way of handling vertical alignment in TIKZ. Let me elaborate an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
          \node (A1) at (0,4) {($\overset{\surd}{1}$ \indent 2)};
          \node (B1) at (0,3) {($\overset{\surd}{3}$ \indent 4)};

          \node (A) at (2,4) {$\phi_1$} ;
          \node (B) at (2,3) {$\phi_2$} ;

          \draw [->, line width=1pt] (A) -- (A1)
        node [near start, above]
            {
                \footnotesize{R1}
            };

            \node (A2) at (6,4) {$7^1$ \indent $8^1$ \indent $3^1$ \indent $4^1$\indent $\parallel$ 2};
            \node (B2) at (6,3) {$1^3$ \indent $2^3$ \indent $5^3$ \indent $6^3$\indent $\parallel$ 4};

            %fake caption
            \node at (8,4.5) {fake};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which results in this:
[image: Output of the code]

I just want to know is ther any way to force the lines into a bottom line here so that `$\phi_1$` and the left would be aligned? Should I use phantom to do so or is there any thing better I am unaware of?
The next point is about the word "fake" in the top right corner. I want it over the "2" but I have placed it as a node. I could use `\overset{fake}{\overline{2}}` to have a "fake" above the "2" but it pushes the line to the left which is not desired. And as you might have guessed I also need a line between "fake" and "2" should I use `\overline{2}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you're using `amsmath` for the `\overset`.  To get the alignment right, stick a `[every node/.style = {anchor = base}]` as an argument to `{tikzpicture}`, and to make the arrow from `\phi` work, you should change its target to `(A-|A1.east)` (this specifies the point which is at the intersection of a horizontal line from A and a vertical line through A1.east, which gives a nice flat arrow).

For your second question, I suggest you abandon your current approach and use some TikZ libraries.  In particular, you should use `chains` to get nodes in a line easily and with any spacing you like, and `positioning` to put the "fake" in the right place.  Once you do that, you can use a `\draw` command to get the line you want.

I've also used `scopes` to simplify the code.  It allows me to write braces `{...}` instead of `\begin{scope}...\end{scope}`.  (If you don't know: scopes in TikZ allow you to pass optional arguments which take effect locally.)  Final code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains, scopes, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 [every node/.style = {anchor = base}]
      \node (A1) at (0,4) {($\overset{\surd}{1}$ \quad 2)};
      \node (B1) at (0,3) {($\overset{\surd}{3}$ \quad 4)};

      \node (A) at (2,4) {$\phi_1$} ;
      \node (B) at (2,3) {$\phi_2$} ;

      \draw [->, line width=1pt] (A) -- (A-|A1.east)
       node [near start, above]
        {
            \footnotesize{R1}
        };

      { [start chain, every node/.append style = on chain, node distance = 1em]
       \node at (4,4) {$7^1$};
       \node {$8^1$}; \node {$3^1$}; \node {$4^1$}; \node {$\parallel$};
       \node (two) {$2$};
      }
      { [start chain, every node/.append style = on chain, node distance = 1em]
       \node at (4,3) {$1^3$};
       \node {$2^3$}; \node {$5^3$}; \node {$6^3$}; \node {$\parallel$}; \node {$4$};
      }

      \node (fake) [above = 1ex of two.north] {fake};
      \draw (fake.south east) -- (fake.south west);

      \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I update the code now to reflect a full tex document. The first problem is solved, but how about the fake keyword and line below it? Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Included now, second paragraph plus updated example.

Comment: @Ryan Reich: Can you please tell me how can I markup code block like that?

Comment: @an_ant: I used the `scopes` library.  I've edited my answer to explain.

Comment: @an_ant: Paste the code you want to highlight and select that piece of code, then chose the button which has squares on it (from above). The buttons mouse over hint says "code block" (I suppose).

Comment: @an_ant, @Yasser: Oh, I didn't realize that's what (s)he meant.  Yes, code blocks can be created by indenting a paragraph by four or more spaces.

Comment: @Yasser, @Ryan Reich: Why doesn't it break lines in code appropriately?

Comment: @an_ant: You mean why does it allow very long lines which require scrolling?  You'll have to ask Jeff Atwood about that :)  I suppose it's because the code block is supposed to be something of a "verbatim" environment, and at least in some languages (Python), whitespace is important.  So the code is displayed exactly as written.

Comment: @Ryan Reich: I was actually alluding to the fact that in my answer, I've written: `\node (waiting) {};` `\node (critical) [below of waiting] {};` `\node (leave critical) [right of waiting] {};` on 3 separate lines, each one indented with exactly 4 spaces - why does it than displays those lines like they are one line?

Comment: @an_ant: Oh, I see.  You put your code block inside a list; apparently, you need to indent it four *additional* spaces.  You can use the preview to make sure it looks right before committing.

Comment: @Ryan Reich: why \node[strike out] does not cross the node out in your code? Am I missing some thing?

Comment: @Yasser: Did you try `\node[strike out, draw]`?  The slash is considered part of the "shape", like the border in a normal (rectangular) node.

Comment: It totally worked out but I don't get your point about "slash". Do you mean the line which crosses the text of the node when using "strike out" style? Meanwhile, thanks a lot.

Comment: @Yasser: Yes, that line.

Answer (score 1):

This **exact** problem is discussed in [pgfmanual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (you can read it running `texdoc pgf` in bash, also) in "3 Tutorial: A Petri-Net for Hagen" (pg. 37) and in "5 Tutorial: Putting a Diagram in Chains" (pg. 56). Two placing methods discussed there are:

- **3.8 Placing Nodes Using Relative Placement** - works like this. You use

  ```
  \node (waiting) {};
  \node (critical) [below of waiting] {};
  \node (leave critical) [right of waiting] {};
  ```

  to place the first node, and every following one in relative positioning to that 1st one, or any other node you name.
- **5.3 Aligning the Nodes Using Matrices** - is done this way

  ```
  \matrix[row sep=1mm,column sep=5mm] {
  % First row:
  & & & & \node [terminal] {+}; & \\
  % Second row:
  \node [nonterminal] {unsigned integer}; &
  \node [terminal] {.}; &
  \node [terminal] {digit};  &
  \node [terminal] {E}; &
                        &
  \node [nonterminal] {unsigned integer}; \\
  % Third row:
  & & & & \node [terminal] {-}; & \\
  };
  ```

  You actually add nodes in matrix, like you would add values in tables - members of rows and columns are therefore aligned appropriately. In combination with `row sep`, `column sep` and leaving atoms in matrix empty you can modify spaces between particular items in matrix.

Comment: For this matter, I'd like placing nodes using coordinates and not using the matrix. About the relative placement, i don't think it would solve the base line problem. Actually if there are imbalanced nodes (in hight). I have the experience of using relative coordinates and it made me to use phantoms to level that up (may be my bad!).